# Task.Run() blocks startup of .net core application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

```
public void Configure(...)
{
   ...
   Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var eventBus = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();
                eventBus.Subscribe<Event1, Event1Handler>("key");
            });
}
```

My scenerio covers rabbitMq absence on application startup. What I am trying to achieve here, is to run this task in the background and let my application start in normal way.

What I get is that application still waits for execution of this task and after that is responsive. I would like to use .RetryForever() inside this task to establish connection with rabbitmq and then subscribe to queue, but in the meantime my service should work without rabbitmq.

What am I doing wrong?
Maybe I should change the way I try to initialize connection with rabbitMq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced Task.Run invokation with proper class derving from BackgroundService.

Then I in registered it as HostedService in Program.cs method: `IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)`

```
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
            });
```

With this I achieved webApi start without interuption and background process which is trying to connect to rabbitmq until it achieves it.